# android:launchMode="singleInstance" is making the app very slow

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have 2 activities in my app. The A activity is the launcher one. When I run the app the very first time, the launcher activity runs, but when I press the home button and restart the app from there by clicking the app icon, I always get the B activity running.
I want to make sure that the activity A should always run when starting the app.

This is the manifest code:

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.velosys.smsManager.Activities.a"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.velosys.smsManager.Activities.b" />
</application>
```

Using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` serves my purpose,but it makes the movement from one activity to another really very slow.Can you please suggest me any option for `android:launchMode="singleInstance".Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to override onUserLeaveHint() method in B activity (this will register Home button pressed event) and then create intent

```
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(startMain);
```

which isn't really an ideal solution

EDIT:

yeah sry, best solution would be that you call finish() inside onPause() method of B activity

Comment: Sorry sir,but i need an answer on which i should rely upon.

Comment: check the edit and remove android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Comment: Sir,i can't use finish() inside onPause() method of B activity because in the case when any call will arrive on the device,the  onPause() will be called and the user will have to start the whole process again.Can you please suggest me any way to handle home button clicking?

Comment: yeah you can put finish then in onUserLeaveHint() which will be called only on Home button press. That way incoming call will not finish the activity but only home press will

Comment: It only handles the home button pressing or the back button pressing also because it if also handles back button pressing,it may create problem for me.

Comment: it is only handling home button pressing
back button is handled with onBackPressed or by filtering pressed key in onKeyDown method. but it is not really certain... I have tested it and on some devices it registeres the back button as well:
this is detailed explanation: http://researcharea.blogspot.com/2011/03/onuserleavehint-android.html

Comment: Sir,you are really helpful,but i am a noob and don't have that much expertise.please suggest me any not messing up kind of idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21068/discussion-between-kjurkovic-and-user1726619)